# kotlin multi-platform to javascript : naming of the method not respected

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I use the gradle kotlin multi-platform  plugin to build something in java and js

My issue is in the js version, the name of the function/class is not consistent:

in my kotlin, I define a function "launch()", in the js buid, it will be "launch12434()"

any idea how to correct-it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@JsName` annotation to give a specific name for your method. It looks like this;

```
@JsName("launch")
fun launch() {

}
```

More info [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-js-name/index.html).